# Не получается вытащить значение из select

Tags: javascript, html

Есть много div блоков, в которых имеются данные о товаре. Пытаюсь вытащить значение из селекта

```
<div class="uk-width-1-2">
      <div class="uk-margin">
           <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-select">Выберите цену:</label>
          <div class="item_list uk-form-controls">
                   <select  id="form-stacked-select" class="uk-select">
                        <option value="50" selected="selected" >150 мл - 50 рублей</option>
                       <option value="70" >200 мл - 70 рублей</option>
                          <option value="100" >300 мл - 100 рублей</option>
                </select>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Пробую:

```
 sel = parentBox.querySelector('.item_list').innerHTML; 
 console.log(sel);
```

Получаю в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Теперь пытаюсь пойти дальше:

```
sel = parentBox.querySelector('.item_list').innerHTML,
check = sel.getElementById('form-stacked-select').options.selectedIndex;
console.log(check);
```

Получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `check = document.getElementById('form-stacked-select').options.selectedIndex;`

Comment: Да, так работает, уже проверял. Но у меня таких блоков много, а нужно выбирать для конкретного, в котором была нажата кнопка

Comment: У Вас не может/не дожно быть "много" блоков с одинаковыми `id`. Используйте аттрибут `class` и `querySelector`

Comment: у вас sel - строка с html содержимым списка. Откуда у строки метод getElementById?